# Show if following polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

$p(x) = x^7+20x-6$.

If someone can give me the idea I would appreciate.

Comment: Are you familiar with Eisenstein's criterion?

Answer (score 2):

$2$ is a prime that divides both $6$ and $20$.

$2$ is a prime that does not divide $1$.

$4=2^2$ does not divide $6$.

Thus by Eisenstein's criterion $p(x)=1x^7 + 20x-6~$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Since $\gcd(1,6,20)=1~$ and $~p(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, then $p(x)$ is also irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: Your first answer (Eisenstein) is good, but your second (concerning roots) is faulty.  There are many polynomials that are reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ but have no rational roots: $(x^2 + 1)^2$, for example.

Comment: Good point. Rational root theorem only guarantees no linear factors over $\mathbb{Q}$. I will edit.